# infinite loop in python?

Tags: python, knapsack-problem

I've been working on the Knapsack problem implementation, but I could not implement it right  the code just keeps going into this infinite loop of while(true)
here's the code:

```
class KSBB:
    global x
    global y
    x=[]
    y=[]
    global sp
    sp=0
    global cw
    global cp
    global nw
    global np
    cw,cp,nw,np=0,0,0,0
    global k
    k=0
    global pi
    pi=0
def __init__(self,a,b,c):
    self.weights=a
    self.values=b
    self.c=c
    x=len(self.weights)
    y=len(self.weights)
```

Bound method:

```
def bound(self):
    global cp
    found=False
    bv=0
    n=len(self.weights)
    np=cp
    nw=cw
    pi=k
    while(pi < n and ~found):
        if(nw+self.weights[pi] <= self.c):
            nw+=self.weights[pi]
            np+=self.values[pi]
            y.append(1)
        else:
            bv=np+((self.c-nw)*(self.values[pi]/self.weights[pi]))
            found=True
            #y.append(0)
        pi+=1
    if found:
        pi-=1
        return bv
    else:
        return np
```

Branching Method:

```
def Knapsack(self):
    n=len(self.weights)
    while True:
        global sp
        while (self.bound() <= sp):
            while(k !=0 and y[k] !=1):
                k-=1 
            if (K==0):return
            y[k]=0
            cw-=self.weights[k]
            cp-=self.values[k]
        cw=nw
        cp=np
        k=pi
        print k
        if (k==n):              
            sp=cp
            x=y
            k=n-1
        else:
            y[k]=0
```

Output Method:

```
def output(self):return sp
```

Comment: I think the `global` keyword doesn't do what you think it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (K==0)
```

should probably be

```
if (k==0)
```

Just a typo...

It is easy to localize this problem - you know where you want to terminate your loop and the only thing which can go wrong is your `if` statement. Spotting such things is easy and one of the most basic things to master in programming. You need to learn debugging as soon as your programs start to be longer than 5 lines.

Comment: There are plenty of warnings about single letter variable names out there. Some people just always think they know better and that it will be fine if they are careful enough.

Comment: @sashkello
Thanks for your help, after fixing the typo it's still in infinite loop it looks like I've a logic error in the implementation itself that I can't find.

Comment: Print k at the beginning of that while and see what it gives you. Is it stuck in that loop or maybe in some of the inner loops? That will be the first step to find out the problem.

Comment: actually it's stuck in the while loop it keeps outputting "0"

I run the code with these sets:

    self.weights=[4,5,8,3]
    self.values=[8,10,15,4]
    self.c=11

Comment: So it never enters while (self.bound() <= sp):

Comment: it enters self.bound loop but the values is changed instantaneously and it becomes constant at the end k=0 but it doesn't return anything

Comment: @sashkello I started the implementation from scratch with other new view and now it works. The problem was with my understanding of the algorithm.
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @user2540671 Would be helpful to others if you post the fixed code.

Answer (score 1):

`~found` is a bitwise complement. I think you mean `not found`!

```
>>> ~False
-1             # True
>>> ~True
-2             # also True!
```

Comment: That wouldn't result in an infinite loop though because it should break out with 'pi'. Another error though it seems.